# What is the distance between the line and plane if it is parallel?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, education

So far, I've gotten that the line is parallel to the plane $x = 2 + t$, $y = -3 + 2t$, $z = 1 + 4t$
With the vector of that being $U$ is $(1,2,4)$ and the plane $2y-z = 1$ with the vector $V$ being $(0,2,-1)$.

I'm kind of stuck because I'm not entirely sure where to go from here, any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first set of equations is a line through $V$ in the direction of $U$, but the description is quite jumbled.  Are you asking about the distance from this line to the plane $2y-z=1$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm paraphrasing a bit here, the exact question is show that the line x = 2 + t,  y = -3 + 2t,  z = 1 +4t is parallel to the plane 2y - z = 1. What is the distance between the line and the plane?

Comment: OK, do you know how to find the Normal to a plane?

Comment: Not really, no... I'm really new to this and I've tried different examples and just really don't know where to go after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be reduced by calculate the distance from a point to a line (or plan):
You have to take a point A ((2, -3, 1) for example) from line and a point H ((0, 0, -1) for example) from plan.

Here $\overrightarrow{AH} = (-2, 3, -2)$

As you know normal of plan : $\overrightarrow n = (0, 2, -1)$, distance is :
$$d(H, (d)) = d(A, (P)) = \frac{\|\overrightarrow{AH} \dot{} \overrightarrow n\|}{\|\overrightarrow n\|}$$

Comment: Umm, sorry to ask, but what is the symbol ∧ used for?

Comment: @Anon I think he means the dot product, perhaps. It should be noted that $\wedge$ is not the usual notation for dot product by any means, though.

Comment: Alright, well we haven't done cross product and apparently won't be covering it, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Updated with dot product. Anyway the equation is logic. This is projection on normal of plan.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much! I was also able to find it by using the point (2, -3, 1) + k(0, -2, 1) and plugged that into the equation of the plane, solved for k and gave the distance with |kv|! Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes but not really fast, you have to solve an equation. Here answer is direct: (3x2+2x1)/sqrt(5)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  can you calculate the distance from a point to a plane (use the normal to the plane).  Pick any two points on the line.  If the distance to the plane is the same, the line is parallel to the plane, and the distance is what you calculate.

Comment: And... there is a distance formula that allows you to do that, once you have an equation of that plane. And that's where the Normal comes in, Anonymous. Are you learning this from a textbook?

Comment: Learning both from prof and textbook. She has notes I'm reading off of and they don't really show much to help with the equation. Would "Normal" just being normalizing or?

Comment: The normal to a plane is a vector perpendicular to the plane.  Usually when you get the description of the equation of a plane it is explained how to get the normal of that.  You could see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_to_a_plane